# Any angular example for knob-style Rotary Switch?

Tags: angularjs

Hi i'm looking for an Angular.js example like this,
http://www.jqueryscript.net/form/Knob-Style-Rotary-Switch-Plugin-with-jQuery-rotarySwitch.html

Ideally a complete path from rotary switch to posting some commands to the service side, based in the switch position.

Any good example please ?

Otherwise i plan to write a angular module using this sample jquery file, every time the rotary switch moves to a new location, it's call $http.post to let service side know. The main module will use this rotary switch module. But really don't want to write my own.

Comment: Angular doesn't provide any components. Angular-bootstrap-UI has some components you can use, but I don't think it has a knob-style rotary switch. So basically you're going to have to "write your own", aka re-purpose the example from the link you posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like mentioned in the comments I also think that there is probably no directive for that rotary switch plugin.

So something like in the demo below should work for this. I've just created a directive where I've initialized the jquery plugin inside the link method (dom is ready to manipulate inside postLink).

To reduce http traffic I've added a timeout so that the callback is called at a lower rate. (see `rotKnob_delayedCallback` in `DEFAULT_OPTS`)

You could write a directive for every jQuery plugin where you can't find a wrapper directive.

Please also have a look at the browser console. In jsfiddle you can see the post echo of the position in the console.

Here is also the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/yn8c0p5m/) to the demo below.

```js
angular.module('demoApp', ['rotaryKnobModule'])
 .factory('knobService', KnobService)
    .controller('mainController', MainController)
    
angular.module('rotaryKnobModule', [])
 .constant('DEFAULT_OPTS', {
     // Minimal value
                minimum: 0,

                // Maximum value
                maximum: 12,

                // Step size
                step: 1,

                // Snap to steps in motion
                snapInMotion: true,

                // Start point in deg
                beginDeg: 0,

                // Length in deg
                lengthDeg: 360,

                // // Which value will used, if the the start and the end point at the same deg.
                minimumOverMaximum: true,

                // Show input element
                showInput: false,

                // Show deg marks
                showMarks: false,

                // Theme class
                themeClass: 'defaultTheme',
                
                // custom option for directive
                rotKnb_delayedCallback: 500 // in ms
    })
    .directive('rotaryKnob', RotaryKnob);

function MainController(knobService, $timeout) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.position = 0;
    vm.options = {
     minimum: 0,
        maximum: 100
    };
    vm.onChange = function(pos) {
     console.log('current position change handler', pos);
        
        knobService.postPos(pos).then(function(response){
         console.log('success', response)
        }, function(response) {
         console.log('failed');
        }); 
    }
}

function KnobService($http) {
 return {
     postPos: function(pos) {
            var data = $.param({
                json: JSON.stringify({
                    position: pos
                })
            });
         return $http.post('/echo/json/', data);
        }
    }
}

function RotaryKnob($timeout) {
    return {
        scope: {},
        bindToController: {
            pos: '=',
            options: '=?',
            onChange: '&?'
        },
        controllerAs: 'rotKnobCtrl',
        template: '<input type="text" class="rotarySwitch"/>',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
         var options = scope.rotKnobCtrl.options,
             ctrl = scope.rotKnobCtrl,
                pos = 0, changeTimeout;
                
            //console.log(options);
            var $rotKnob = $(element).rotaryswitch(options);
   $rotKnob.on('change', function() {
             pos = parseInt($(this).val());
             scope.rotKnobCtrl.pos = pos;
                
                if ( !changeTimeout ) // reduce update rate to server
                    changeTimeout = $timeout(function() {
                        ctrl.onChange({pos: pos});
                        changeTimeout = null;
                    }, options.rotKnb_delayedCallback);
                    
                scope.$apply();
            })
        },
        controller: function(DEFAULT_OPTS) {
   var self = this;
            self.pos = 0;
            //console.log(self.options);
            self.options = angular.extend({}, DEFAULT_OPTS, self.options);
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/r12r/com.redwhitesilver.rotarySwitch/master/jquery.rotaryswitch.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.4/angular.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/r12r/com.redwhitesilver.rotarySwitch/master/jquery.rotaryswitch.js"></script>
<div ng-app="demoApp" ng-controller="mainController as mainCtrl">
    <rotary-knob 
        pos="mainCtrl.position" 
        options="mainCtrl.options"
        on-change="mainCtrl.onChange(pos)"
        ></rotary-knob>
    Current position {{mainCtrl.position}}
</div>
```

Comment: just curious, how long have you been studying Angular ? your example is so sophisticated, many admires :)

Comment: Thanks. :-) I think I've started learning angular and javascript over a year ago around Nov. 2014. But coding is just a hobby and I'm still learning. I also haven't coded any large app yet. Just small demos like your directive. Because coding as one person at anything larger is quite time consuming. I've some app ideas but I think I still need to learn more to bring one into production. Answering questions here at SO also helps to learn Angular.

Comment: Best luck to your app ideas and i'm sure you can do great with you skills !